# checking to see if a character in a string is a number/integer

Tags: java

```
public class KebabCaseToCamelCase {
    public String kebabToCamel(String str){
        str = str.substring(0,1).toLowerCase() + str.substring(1);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(str);

        int strLength = str.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++){
            if (builder.charAt(i) == '-'){
                builder.deleteCharAt(i);
                builder.replace(i, i+1, 
                String.valueOf(Character.toUpperCase(
                builder.charAt(i))));
                strLength--;
            }
        }

        return builder.toString();
        

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KebabCaseToCamelCase obj = new KebabCaseToCamelCase();
        String modifiedString = obj.kebabToCamel("geeks-for-geeks");
        System.out.println(modifiedString);
        
    }

    
}
```

the code above converts any string written in kebab cased style to camel case style. Now the challenge is to ensure that a string in this format: "a-1c" does not pass the test as we will be presented with "a1C" instead of "aC". how do I manipulate the code above to obtain the latter output.

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All characters have an index in the ASCII table. You can convert any char to an integer to retrieve the actual ASCII index of the char.

Example:
If you convert the char '1' to int using typecasting, the int will store the value 49. So if check if the casted int is in range 48 - 57, the char will hold a number between '0' and '9'. You can then handle this char however you want.

Here is a small but useful ASCII table that will help you:
https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: Does 'á' have an index in the ASCII table?  Does 'Ω'?  Does '☺'?  (Java characters are UTF-16 values representing all characters Unicode’s basic multilingual plane.  They are not just ASCII values.)

Comment: @VGR yes they do, look at 160 and 234. I am not a programmer with 10 years of experience, means I don't know 100% of the background of things like these. I just wanted to help in this specific problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use isDigit() by adding this if statement to another (but identical) for loop:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html

```
    import java.lang.*;

    for (int i = 0; i < strLength; i++){
       if (Character.isDigit(builder.charAt(i))){   
          builder.deleteCharAt(i);
       }
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i))

Character.isLetter(str.charAt(i))

Comment: You answered the title, but not the question.